# Trying to create a socket.io connection in my React application. How can I get this code below to work?

Tags: reactjs, express, websocket, socket.io, chat

The code had worked before previously but that was before I introduced these specific namespaces because I didn't want websockets to run on the other pages of my website but a specific route so not sure why this isnt working

```
const http = require("http");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");

// Create an HTTP server
const server = http.createServer(app);

// Set up Socket.IO
const io = socketIo(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});
// Create a function to handle chat namespace connections
const createChatNamespace = (namespace) => {
  console.log('Creating chat namespace:', namespace);
  try {
    const chatNamespace = io.of(namespace);

    chatNamespace.on("connection", (newSocket) => {
      console.log(`A user connected to chat namespace ${namespace}:`, newSocket.id);

      newSocket.emit('testEvent', 'Server says hello to client');

      newSocket.on('clientTestResponse', (responseMessage) => {
        console.log('Client test response:', responseMessage);
      });
      

      newSocket.on("chatMessage", async (message) => {
        try {
          console.log(`Received message in chat namespace ${namespace}:`, message);
          // Handle and broadcast chat messages within the chat namespace
          chatNamespace.emit("newChatMessage", message);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(`Error handling chatMessage event in namespace ${namespace}:`, error);
        }
      });

      newSocket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log(`User disconnected from chat namespace ${namespace}:`, socket.id);
      });
    });
  } catch (namespaceError) {
    console.error(`Error creating chat namespace ${namespace}:`, namespaceError);
  }
};

try {
  // Set up a dynamic chat namespace for /message/:username
  app.use("/message/:username", (req, res) => {
    try {
      const username = req.params.username;
      const namespace = `/message/${username}`;
      createChatNamespace(namespace);
      res.send(`Chat namespace created for user: ${username}`);
    } catch (namespaceError) {
      res.status(500).send(`Error creating chat namespace for user: ${username}`);
    }
  });
} catch (setupError) {
  console.error('Error setting up chat namespaces:', setupError);
}
```

here is the relevant server side code

```
let {username} = useParams();
    const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticated")
    const storedUsername = localStorage.getItem("username")
    console.log(storedUsername)
    console.log(username)
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('default');
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]); // State to store messages
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
    const [senderData, setSenderData] = useState(null);
    const [receiverData, setReceiverData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        try {
          // Make an API request to retrieve user data for sender and receiver
          const fetchSenderData = fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/user/${storedUsername}`);
          const fetchReceiverData = fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/user/${username}`);
      
          Promise.all([fetchSenderData, fetchReceiverData])
            .then(([senderResponse, receiverResponse]) => Promise.all([senderResponse.json(), receiverResponse.json()]))
            .then(([senderData, receiverData]) => {
              setSenderData(senderData);
              setReceiverData(receiverData);
      
              console.log('Sender Data:', senderData);
              console.log('Receiver Data:', receiverData);
      
              // Create socket connection with the appropriate namespace
              try {
                console.log('Attempting to create socket connection...');
                const newSocket = io(`http://localhost:8000`);
                console.log('Socket created:', newSocket);
                setSocket(newSocket);
      
                newSocket.on('connect', () => {
                    console.log('Socket connected:', newSocket.id);
                    // Test that the socket connection is established
                  });
      
                  newSocket.on('testEvent', (message) => {
                    console.log('Test Event Message:', message);
                    newSocket.emit('clientTestResponse', 'Client received test event');
                  });
      
                newSocket.on('chatMessage', (receivedMessage) => {
                  console.log('Received Chat Message:', receivedMessage);
                  setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, receivedMessage]);
                });
      
                return () => {
                  // Clean up the socket connection when the component unmounts
                  newSocket.disconnect();
                };
              } catch (socketError) {
                console.error('Error creating socket connection:', socketError);
              }
            })
            .catch(fetchError => {
              console.error('Error fetching user data:', fetchError);
            });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error in useEffect:', error);
        }
      }, [username, storedUsername]);
      
      const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        try {
          event.preventDefault();
          if (message.trim() !== '' && socket) {
            socket.emit('chatMessage', { sender: senderData, receiver: receiverData, text: message });
            setMessage('');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error in handleSubmit:', error);
        }
      };
```

relevant client side code

What I expected was to get the console logs in my server side but I haven't been able to get any server side logs past this line
Creating chat namespace:, namespace

Comment: I don't see where do you connect to the namespace in the client code